# Examples of Log-Lipschitz and nonLog-Lipschitz functions satisfying certain conditions

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

A function $f$ is Log-Lipschitz if there exists a constant $C >0$ such that
\begin{equation}
|f(x) - f(y)| \le C|x-y| |\log|x-y||
\end{equation}

I am trying to construct two functions with the following properties.

First function is $f\in \mathcal{C}^1((0,a])$ ,$a>0$ and log-Lipschitz continuous on $[0,a]$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{x \to0^+} x^q|f'(x)|=+\infty, \forall q \geq 1
\end{equation}
Second function is $g\in \mathcal{C}^1((0,a])$ continuous on $[0,a]$ but Holder continuous on $[0,a]$ for no $\alpha<1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{x \to0^+} x|g'(x)|<+\infty.
\end{equation}
I tried constructing but not getting through much.
Thanks in advance.